# Firefox is showing error when I enter a floating number in number type textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, textbox

Below is my textbox:

```
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" name="payment-textbox" min="1" max="100000" maxlength="9" class="payment" placeholder="--" value=""/>
```

This works fine in Google Chrome. But when I try to enter a floating number in mozilla firefox, it creates a red border around the box. Is there any way to stop firefox to validate float number?

Comment: `input type=number` accepts a localized value only. If your localization settings use a comma as decimal delimiter, you've to enter comma as a decimal limiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify step attribute.

```
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" name="payment-textbox" min="1" max="100000" maxlength="9" class="payment" placeholder="--" step="0.01" value=""/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is a lot more tolerant to avoid programming errors like this. as Huxdit said, you have to include a step attribute

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
```